# Python Django templates not found

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm having trouble with connecting django templates.

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: E:\CS\Udemy\Python and Django Full Stack\Django\charity\templates\posts\post_base.html (Source does not exist)

Actually it has to be charity\posts\templates\post_base.html

In my settings.py

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'posts',
    'comments',
    'rest_framework',
    'bootstrap4',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
    # 'charity.middleware.SessionExpiredMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'charity.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

What I expected is django loads templates in a separate app.

Comment: please post view and complete error trace

Comment: Can you error your templates directory structure with views

Answer (score 0):

Change

> Setting.py
> like this :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and make sure to make the template html file in this folder order

> Project-Name>App-Name>Template>Appname>base.html